# Javascript code, didn't figure out what's wrong

Tags: javascript, html

i just get the function back and no calculation , what's wrong?
I can't figure this out yet.. this is so annoying

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Human(age, name, lastname) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.born = born;
    }
    function born() {
        var currentyear = 2015;
        var born = this.age - currentyear;
    return born;
    }

    var asaf = new Human(16,"Asaf","shlush");
    var daniel = new Human(19 , "Daniel" , "Bivas");

    document.write(asaf.born);
```

Comment: We need more context. What is calling your functions and when?

Comment: document.write , son

Comment: asaf.born is not a function call, and I'm not your son.

Answer (score 1):

you need to call the method, `document.write(asaf.born());`

Answer (score 0):

The born function should be within the Human declaration.

```
function Human(age, name, lastname) {
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
    this.lastname = lastname;

    this.born = function () {
        var currentyear = 2015;
        var born = this.age - currentyear;
        return born;
    }
}


var asaf = new Human(16,"Asaf","shlush");
var daniel = new Human(19 , "Daniel" , "Bivas");

document.write(asaf.born());
```

Note the parenthesis around the function call in the last line as well.

Comment: the line ```this.born = born;``` isn`t doing anything

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the function `born` isn't defined on the `Human` object.

Try this:

```
 function Human(age, name, lastname) {
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.born = function(){
        return 2015 - this.age;
    };
};

var asaf = new Human(16,"Asaf","shlush");
asaf.born() // 1999
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to call the function: `asaf.born()`.

You might also consider adding `born` as a method to the `Human` prototype. You get the same result, but it's probably better practice. Something like:

```
function Human(age, name, lastname) {
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

Human.prototype.wasBorn = function () {
    var currentyear = 2015;
    var born = this.age - currentyear;
    return born;
}
```

[Here you can see both results working.](http://jsfiddle.net/xeajL5kp/)

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by your self just by writing debugger in your javascript code and then open it in browser with inspect element console screen and then refresh it and then debug your javascript code there in browser.

you can simply check which functions gets call and which is not. you can also check value for all elements there.
so, by that you might able to check that if function returns the value for born or not?

Comment: he did not says how he can debug it , the problem is he is stuck somewhere, and he don't know where we fails, if you can then try to solve his problem.